# getDefaultSharedPreferences in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-preferences

I was just guessing how to access the DefaultSharedPreferences (set in a PreferenceActivity) from an application in a BroadcastReceiver, knowing that onReceive method comes with Context and Intent?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BroadcastReceiver:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware of PreferenceManager's static method.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of it, we can see getDefaultSharedPreferences actually uses getSharedPreferences. So we can use getSharedPreferences the same we getDefaultSharedPreferences uses it.

In this specific case (onReceive of a BroadcastReceiver) :

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```